# Where Elasticsearch store the data on Mac

Tags: elasticsearch

Similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694201/where-are-data-files-of-elasticsearch-on-a-standard-debian-install) about debian. I have non-customized installation and I wonder where the data is actually stored. It is not in `/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/{nameOfYourIndex}/(0-4}/index` as indicated in the accepted answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Mac, the data is stored in the `data` sub-folder of your elasticsearch installation folder.

See the [directory layout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-targz.html#zip-targz-layout) for normal installations, i.e. neither Linux nor Windows.

Comment: Fixed, @AndrewProck ;-)

Comment: you can re-up that answer @AndrewProck ;-)

Answer (score 13):

On OS X (El Capitan) installed through `brew` it is found in `/usr/local/var/elasticsearch`

Answer (score 10):

On your computer i.e. Mac OS X you can use the command:

```
brew info elasticsearch

# or

brew info elasticsearch[@version] i.e. brew info elasticsearch@5.6
```

and you see where data are.

Here are my directories:

```
==> Caveats
Data:    /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_xxx.log
Plugins: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/plugins/
Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/
```

Answer (score 4):

OS X Sierra 10.12.6: `/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch`

Answer (score 2):

It can be found the file `config/elasticsearch.yml` available in your installation directory. Look for the `path.data` directive.

For example, for OS X (Sierra) installed through `brew`, the data is found in `/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/`.

To find the installation directory, execute `brew list <package-name>` if installed with `brew`

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS BigSur, 11.x and higer:
/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/brew.html
for a update version of folders.