# Where does elasticsearch store data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have managed to install and try elasticsearch.

I thought i need to install a nosql server like mongodb. 
elasticsearch seems to embbed its own storage or database system.

So, i think elasticsearch is not just a search tool. 
It also provides storage and database functions. Is this correct ?

Thanks

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126261/where-elasticsearch-store-the-data-on-mac/36126351#36126351

Comment: yes that's correct.  It is a datastore as well . Read more https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql

Comment: ok is it possible to change datastore technology ? And if yes, which one is more efficient ?