# How to assign unassigned shards in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, sharding

I have the following setup in elasticsearch

```
[root elasticsearch]$ curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
"cluster_name" : "iresbi",
"status" : "red",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 3,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
"active_primary_shards" : 0,
"active_shards" : 0,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 10,
"delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
"active_shards_percent_as_number" : 0.0
}
```

I have 3 nodes which are acting as both data node as well as master, currently the searches in the cluster are failing with the following exception

```
[2017-04-24T01:36:44,134][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [node-1] All shards failed for phase: [query]
org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: null
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException
```

when i did a cat on shards i get the following output

```
[root elasticsearch]$ curl localhost:9200/_cat/shards?pretty
customer 4 p UNASSIGNED    
customer 4 r UNASSIGNED    
customer 2 p UNASSIGNED    
customer 2 r UNASSIGNED    
customer 3 p UNASSIGNED    
customer 3 r UNASSIGNED    
customer 1 p UNASSIGNED    
customer 1 r UNASSIGNED    
customer 0 p UNASSIGNED    
customer 0 r UNASSIGNED
```

following the disk space usage :

```
[root elasticsearch]$ df
Filesystem                        1K-blocks    Used Available Use%     Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-root            8125880 1587988   6102080  21% /
devtmpfs                            3994324       0   3994324   0%   /dev
tmpfs                               4005212       4   4005208   1%     /dev/shm
tmpfs                               4005212    8624   3996588   1% /run
tmpfs                               4005212       0   4005212   0%   /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda3                            999320    1320    945572   1%   /crashdump
/dev/vda1                            245679  100027    132545  44% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_root-var             6061632 5727072      3604 100%   /var
/dev/mapper/vg_root-tmp             1998672    6356   1871076   1%  /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg_root-var_log         1998672   55800   1821632   3%  /var/log
/dev/mapper/vg_root-apps           25671908  292068  24052736   2%  /apps
/dev/mapper/vg_root-home            1998672  169996   1707436  10% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_root-var_log_audit   1998672    8168   1869264   1% /var/log/audit
/dev/vdb                          257898948   61464 244713900   1% /data
tmpfs                                801044       0    801044   0%      /run/user/1000
```

Need to get these shards assigned back, i can add one more node to the cluster, will that solve the issue? how to get this resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Based on some info gathered by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694201/where-are-data-files-of-elasticsearch-on-a-standard-debian-install), 
if you haven't adapted your /etc/elasticsearch.yml,

the data of elasticsearch will be stored in `/var/lib/elasticsearch/`

So your /var being 100% is likely the cause of your problem.

Proper resolution will be dependent on the amount of data in your shards, presence of replicas or not, and if the /data mount point is the one you intended to use for elasticsearch or not.

In all cases, resolution will be done properly by migrating the indices data to a filesystem which has sufficient space

Another person already asked and got a reply on the migration approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143926/how-to-move-elasticsearch-data-directory)

Comment: Hi i have changed this and restarted ES, but still the shards are in unassigned state

Comment: Did you clear up some space in /var? Also, what do the logs tell you? (depending on your install, they could be available in /var/log/elasticsearch

Comment: I have removed the nodes folder from one of the machines, still didn't help

Comment: And the state of your /var ?

Comment: its still available

Comment: The info you provided in your question shows its usage to be 100%, is it still the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142484/discussion-between-kumard-and-olivier).

Comment: In my case rebooting the instance after increasing the volume worked!